# Can you make a Rubik's Cube pattern with a 4 color flower on every side?

Tags: pattern, rubiks-cube

I enjoy putting my cubes into aesthetically interesting patterns (using legal moves, of course). I'm trying to make a pattern where each side has exactly 4 different colors in the following arrangement:

```
A B A
C D C
A B A
```

I can get 4 sides, but I haven't managed to get all 6 without a color collision somewhere. Is it doable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this?

> [image]
>  [image]
>
>  Algorithm: [`E M2 S`](https://alg.cubing.net/?alg=E_M2_S)

Comment: This is beautiful 

Comment: Avatar checks out.